# How to restrict copy paste of special charatetrs inside a Text Field

Tags: jquery, html

I have this below code for which i have to restrict alphabets and special characters

I have handled it this way

```
<input type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Phone Number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">

function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
        }
        return true;
            }
```

This is working fine , but i couldn't able to restrict copy paste of alphabets and special charaters inside the text field

http://jsfiddle.net/vejjnjoj/1/

Comment: You can use onpaste="return false;" in the html of input textbox, but it will restrict even numbers pasting also.
So you can write a function for the same to restrict the chars and special chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter pasted result. Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vejjnjoj/4/)

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
    }
    return true;
        }

function filterInput() {
var filtered = [];
setTimeout(function(){
    var data = document.querySelector('#mobile').value.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != ' ' && !isNaN(data[i])) {
            filtered.push(data[i]);
        }
     }
     document.querySelector('#mobile').value = filtered.join('');
 }, 100)

}

<input type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Phone Number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onpaste="filterInput()">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use input event to invoke for both keydown and pasting events and filter inputs, like this:

```
$('input#mobile').on('input', function(key){
    // your filtration code
});
```

hope it works!